# How to install Terminator in Rhel8?

Tags: rhel, package-management, rpm, gnome-terminator

I am not able to install Terminator in Rhel 8.  I do not want to install it using "snap".

The process that used to work in Rhel 7 does not work in Rhel8.

Comment: Hello @jvacaq. The Terminator package in CentOS/RHEL 7 was provided by EPEL repository as we can see in this URL ```http://mirrors.up.pt/fedora-epel/7/x86_64/Packages/t/```. However, the EPEL repository for CentOS/RHEL 8 doesn't provide it, as you can see it here: ```http://mirrors.up.pt/fedora-epel/8/Everything/x86_64/Packages/t/```.
The last released version 1.91 is quiet old (2017) and is available at https://launchpad.net/terminator/gtk3/1.91 . You can try to install it using the source code.

Comment: Hi, yes I compiled from source, but now I get this error message: 
You need to install the python bindings for gobject, gtk and pango to run Terminator.

Answer (score 5):

As I already mentioned in the comment, at this moment the terminator package is not available in the [EPEL8 repository](http://mirrors.up.pt/fedora-epel/8/Everything/x86_64/Packages/t/). However, for what I can see in this [ticket request](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1755402#c5), there are some effort to add the last version of terminator to EPEL8 repository.

In the comments we can see that [mattrose](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/mattrose/) worked on a [python3 terminator version](https://code.launchpad.net/~hellodeargrandma/terminator/python3).
I did a few tests of his version and it ran without any apparent issues.

To install it you just need to use his [repository](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/mattrose/python3-terminator/):

```bsh
$ sudo dnf copr enable mattrose/python3-terminator
$ sudo dnf repolist
$ sudo dnf install terminator
```

Of course, this is not a supported/official release, so, is up to you to decide if you want to use it or not.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

This issue seems to have been resolved.  Now, on CentOS 8 (rhel 8) you can simply execute:

```
sudo dnf install epel-release -y
sudo dnf install terminator -y
```

Comment: This worked perfect for me on rhel 8.4. Thank you.

Comment: This worked on CentOS 7